# Erro na função SCROLL dentro do OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, rolamento

Boa tarde Pessoal, a uma semana mais ou menos um cliente veio reclamando que o link do site dele não estava funcionando e eu não conseguia entender o por que, pois o site foi entregue funcionando, era um link que simplesmente rolava a página. Essa semana então percebi que o mesmo tipo de link parou de funcionar em outros sites meu, e é uma função de scroll que eu utilizo a muito tempo, e ela esta apresentando um erro que eu ainda não consegui decifrar, alguém consegue me dar um help?

Estou colocando nas imagens abaixo o código do link que faz a chamada da função pelo onclick, o erro e também a função js que estou usando.

[image: Erro do Navegador]
[image: Chamada do onclick para scroll]
[image: Função em jQuery]

Comment: Eu já testei direto no console do chrome chamar a função scroll() e ela funciona corretamente, percebi então que o erro está no onclick, mas o que seria?

Comment: Os sites a seguir são sites que já fiz e estão dando esse problema:

• http://braganca.adv.br  (o link de scroll está no contato no topo)
• http://happyday-es.com.br  (o link de scroll está em festas no topo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li a respeito, a função `scroll` sendo chamada não corresponde a de sua autoria e sim à função [window.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll), que recebe parametros diferentes, causando esse erro no chrome.

Tente mudar o nome da sua função e verifique se seu problema será resolvido.

Fazendo um teste rápido aqui declarando uma função com outro nome no console e alterando o onclick para chamar esta função, a rolagem funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado Breno Costa, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Eu não tinha cogitado isso pois quando eu chamava a função pelo console, sem o onclick ela funcionava. Então o problema mesmo estava no scroll dentro do onclick.

Comment: Por nada! De resto, ficam os mistérios nas implementações das API's pelos navegadores.. kkk